# Displaying a grid as a text input background

Tags: css, textinput

I'm trying to style a text input to display a "grid" aligned with the text, see example below:

[image: Text input with custom grid background]

I use a fixed-width font, with a fixed letter-spacing. In theory, it should be possible to get the same expected rendering on every browser, but it's a well known fact that fonts are  displayed differently across browsers.

If I get the alignment right in Firefox, it doesn't work on IE etc. As a workaround, I could use different CSS between IE and firefox to show a slightly different background image. But even on Firefox, it seems that the rendering depends on the screen resolution (I got different results on a 4:3 and a 16:9).

Does anyone have an idea regarding how I could accomplish a correct aligmnent between the text and the grid?

Thanks

Comment: create a separate `input` field for every letter/number next to each other

Comment: Yup, but IBANs can be up to 29 characters, plus I have to add Javascript to hop automatically from one field to another, handle "empty fields" in the middle of others, concatenate all the values etc. Seems to be quite laborious...

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around, which may work irrespective of resolution and browser.

Take a span and input field in your div. Show the span and input field overlapping with each other.

Now create a string of '|' having equal character spacing and width as that of input field's character. As these are overlapped it will look like a grid when the user will type.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to input into css file:

```
letter-spacing: 24px;
```

Then you will have spacing after any char, and You can add ready background with grid too.